# Magento admin form not saving the decimal values with decimal

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

For one of my custom module I have following sql setup script

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("


    CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('wholesale')} (
      `wholesale_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `percentage` float(5,3) NOT NULL,
       `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
      `created_time` datetime NULL,
      `update_time` datetime NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`wholesale_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

        ");

    $installer->endSetup();
```

The value passed to this **percentage` float(5,3) NOT NULL,** column is saving with decimal but always with 00 for example. If I save a value 10.23 it save in database as 10.00.

Please help

Comment: Hi, We have same problem as you have faced. So, can you please tell us how can be fix this? Waiting for reply.

Comment: @user2393886 As I have already mentioned in my answer that I truncated the table and inserted first record manually using phpmyadmin.Then after wards when I was saving the data using custom module form it worked for me.

Comment: @user2393886 Reply if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I truncated the table and inserted one record manually and it worked for me.
I am not sure why this happened but this worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue. After clearing the cache with "Flush Magento cache", it started to save properly. In my case, I had altered the column and it was being cached.